# Does Virtualbox support Intel Quick Sync Video?

Tags: virtualbox

I want to make use of hardware acceleration for decoding an h264 encoded MP4 file. However, since I am using `Mac OS`, I cannot use Intel `quick sync video` which only supports Linux and Windows.

Does Virtualbox support Intel `Quick Sync Video`? If I install a guest Linux distribution in Virtualbox, does Intel `quick sync video` work?

Comment: I don't get it! Why is my question voted down? Did I explain unclearly? or my question is off topic?

Answer (score 2):

Quick Sync is Intel's technology, but I think you are interested in GPU virtualization support in VirtualBox. Also it depends from your system hardware whether it is possible to use GPU virtualization, your system needs to support VT-d or GVT-D and your virtualization software need to support GPU passthrough on the other hand.

Qemu, Xen and VMWar should support VT-d, and as far as I know Virtualbox does not support it yet.